# Stop keypress before it happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop the following keypresses to happen before they happen:

> ' " / * - +

I've tried using various variations of the following:

```
<textarea>Here may the forbidden characters not enter</textarea>

<script>
function onKeyDown(event) {   
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

..but haven't succeded. The background is that it's linked to a jQuery which updates a database instantly, but I do not wish to see these characters in the database and need therefor stop them before they happen. Ideas?

Comment: where's the jQuery code? SHow all code relevant to the issue

Comment: i would stop them in the part that talks to the db, not the part that listens to the keyboard...

Comment: @dandavis I wanna make it obvious they're not supposed to be used :)

Comment: @MoMononoke: you can do that to. <input pattern> is the best bet, as it works without JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will prevent `", ', *, +, -, /` characters in a `<textarea>`.

```
$(function(){
    // ", ', *, +, -, /
    var disabledOn = [34, 39, 42, 43, 45, 47];
    $('textarea').on('keypress', function(ev){
    if ($.inArray(ev.which, disabledOn) >= 0){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/msLut4jL/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much.

Comment: that won't stop someone from dropping or pasting invalid data into the DB. use <input pattern> and the `input` event instead of the `keypress` event. that makes it easy to replace() the `.value` once it set by the IME

Comment: @MoMononoke What dandavis says is true, you should also have server validation as well before users try to insert anything into your db.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preventing specific keypresses you could also clean up your textarea on change and keyup events like this:

```
$("#thisTextarea").change(function() { removeSpecialChars($(this)) });

$("#thisTextarea").keyup(function()  { removeSpecialChars($(this)) });

function removeSpecialChars($textarea) {
   $textarea.val($textarea.val().replace(/\'|\"|\/|\*|\-|\+/g,''));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wagbw8nh/

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a good idea to have your client side code write to the database, quite a bad one actually, one solution is to `event.preventDefault()` whenever someone types.

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
  var k = e.keyCode;
  var nonShifted = [222, 191, 189];
  var shifted = [56, 187];
  if (nonShifted.indexOf(k) !== -1 || (shifted.indexOf(k) !== -1 && e.shiftKey)){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/jalexy12/pen/yebJzd)